# Please clarify me about admin-ajax.php?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, cpanel, ajax

Someone know What is "admin-ajax.php" and its function and how it works. Please explain me if any one have fine description about it.

Comment: Sorry but the question is too bread and off-topic due to the nature of the question (programming) and WordPress development. I can see that you've had many questions closed since joined the site, I highly recommend that you visit our help centre to avoid further disappointment.

Answer (score 2):

It is a part of WordPress API.
It handles the request from both front end and backend.
Here is a link of a similar question.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77407/how-does-admin-ajax-php-work